# how to send SMB_COM_SESSION_SETUP_ANDX request via Socket in CIFS in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, smb

how to send SMB_COM_SESSION_SETUP_ANDX request via Socket in CIFS in C# ? I want to send this request and get a response from destination address in C#. I want to send CIFS request in form of CIFS format.

Any code snippet is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us some code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you would need to implement all aspects of the CIFS protocol required for being able to execute the request and interpret the response. The starting point here would be the [CIFS specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cifs/d416ff7c-c536-406e-a951-4f04b2fd1d2b) and/or [Common Internet File System (CIFS) Technical Reference](https://www.thursby.com/sites/default/files/files/CIFS-TR-1p00_FINAL.pdf).

Usually, this request is the second request (after `SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE` for selecting the CIFS/SMB dialect to use) in a CIFS message exchange and represents the user login phase of the protocol.

If all you need is being able to authenticate a user against the CIFS server, the scope might be small enough to make a custom implementation feasible. This depends on what kind of authentication you need, though. If authentication based on a plaintext password is sufficient, you could stick to the simplest kind of authentication mechanism. Otherwise, in case of NTLM/Kerberos (as in the case of plaintext passwords, NTLM should not be used anymore either from a security POV), things get more complex and usually require several roundtrips to complete the authentication process.

An easier alternative is [SMBLibrary](https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary), which implements the protocol based on C#.